# convex function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-\alpha \log(x^2y^2)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to study where the function $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2-\alpha \log(x^2y^2)$ is convex or not in its domain. Do I study the Hessian matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hessian matrix is good. For the derivatives, consider
$$
f(x)=x^2+y^2-2\alpha\log\lvert x\rvert-2\alpha\log\lvert y\rvert
$$
so
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}&=2x-\frac{2\alpha}{x} \\[4px]
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}&=2y-\frac{2\alpha}{y}
\end{align}
and therefore the Hessian matrix is
$$
4\begin{bmatrix}
1+\dfrac{\alpha}{x^2} & 0 \\
0 & 1+\dfrac{\alpha}{y^2}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which is positive definite as long as $\alpha\ge0$.

If $\alpha<0$, there are points where the Hessian matrix is positive definite, points where it's indefinite and points where it's negative definite.

Comment: is positive definite as long as $\alpha\ge0$ so f is convex or not? f is convex only if is semi-positive definite?

Comment: @GiuliaB. The positive semidefinite condition is sufficient, in this case the stronger condition of being positive definite holds (when $\alpha\ge0$). When $\alpha<0$ there are points where the Hessian is even negative definite.

Comment: a matrix 2x2 is semi positive definite if $tr(A)\ge0$ and $det(A)\ge 0$?

Comment: @GiuliaB. Better, when its eigenvalues are $\ge0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 2\alpha\log(x) - 2\alpha\log(y)
$$
is convex in $(0,\infty)^2$ as long as $\alpha\geq0$ because it's the sum of convex functions.
The function is never convex on its domain of definition, $(\mathbb R\setminus\{0\})^2$, for any value of $\alpha$.